# Como instalar uma versão antiga da JDK no windows 7?

Tags: java, jdk

Já tenho algumas versões instaladas na máquina, 1.7 e 1.6.

Agora tenho a necessidade de instalar a versão 1.5, porém quando tento instalar ocorre um erro, falando para desinstalar as versões que possuo do java(JDK).

Não tenho a possibilidade pois tenho outras aplicações usando essas versões, existe alguma possibilidade de fazer isso sem desinstalar as versões que possuo ?

Esse é o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, eu não tenho essa versão instalada.

Desde já agradeço !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instale as diferentes versões do JDK em pastas diferentes. Apenas isso.

Comment: Daniel não parece ser esse o problema do AP, na verdade fiquei na dúvida se punha para excluir ou não e tomei a decisão de por na fila e a comunidade decide.

Comment: JDk remove versoes mais antigas quando se instala mais novas. Não sei se as mais antigas instalam, ao detectar que há outra mais recente.

Comment: Basta customizar a instalação modificando o path de onde os arquivos serão instalados.

Comment: O problema é bastante claro. Basta instalar num folder diferente. Preciso desenhar um gráfico e escrever um texto bíblico de 10 mil linhas para tornar a resposta válida? rsrsr